# How to add multiple bitmap images with text into a table using iText in android?

Tags: android, itext

I want to create a pdf file containing barcode images with text in a table. I am not able to create in this format.

[image: Required output should be like this]

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(qrCodeModelArrayList.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < qrCodeModelArrayList.size(); i++) {

        Bitmap bitmap = qrCodeModelArrayList.get(i).getQrBitMap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream); //use the compression format of your need
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(stream.toByteArray());

        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream1);
        Image bitmapImage = null;
        try {
            bitmapImage = Image.getInstance(stream1.toByteArray());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
        cell.addElement(bitmapImage);
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph(qrCodeModelArrayList.get(i).getQrCodeName());
        p.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell.addElement(p);
        table.addCell(cell);
    }
```

When using this code, I did got output as below:

[image]

I am not able to view my barcode images and all columns are adding in same row. I wanted it in 5 columns .

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: This question was already answered in the [official FAQ](http://developers.itextpdf.com/frequently-asked-developer-questions-7):
 [How to add an image and text to the same cell?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/best-itext-questions-stackoverview/tables/itext7-how-add-image-and-text-same-cell) If the iText 5 answer is needed, see the [old version](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-image-and-text-same-cell).

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse Please check my code

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your question so that it shows the actual problem: you are trying to create a QRCode, which should be done using the [`BarcodeQRCode`](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/latest/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/BarcodeQRCode.html) class. You should then add the code to the PDF using the [`placeBarcode()`](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/latest/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/BarcodeQRCode.html#placeBarcode-com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfContentByte-com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor-float-) method. You can't use the [`createAwtImage()`](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/latest/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/BarcodeQRCode.html#createAwtImage-java.awt.Color-java.awt.Color-) method, because there is no AWT on Android. I think that the code you are currently using has some image-related problem. A QRCode consists of vector data and you convert it to the lossy JPEG format (which is a bad idea, because barcode scanners will have trouble reading JPGs, you should use PNG instead). Also you are compressing the barcode; which doesn't make sense for an image that could be a vector format.

Using the `placeBarcode()` method will add the QRCode as a vector image (using PDF syntax). That is much better than adding a bar code as a raster image.